# How can I access to Dataverse data of all environnements in my tenant?

Tags: powershell, admin, dataverse, power-platform

I'm trying to get all pva bots built in Dataverse for Teams environments of my tenant accross PowerShell and Dataverse web API.

I'm Power Platform admin in this tenant and I declared a service principal as Power Platform Admin  following this documentation. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powershell-create-service-principal)

```
#################################################################
# Now that it has been registered with Microsoft Power Platform, 
# I can authenticate as the service principal itself.
#################################################################
$appId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint prod -TenantID $tenantId -ApplicationId $appId -ClientSecret $secret -Verbose
```

At this point I'm well connected as admin because I can get All environment of my tenant as an Admin.

Then I need to request Dataverse API to get pva bots inside an environment.

```
#################
####  TO DO #####
#################
<#
I have to loop the list of Dataverse for teams environments and for each environment get pva bots
#>


#For the moment I set only one environment that I know there're PVA bots inside
$PowerPlatformOrg = 'XXXXXXXX'    
    #Dynamics 365 Organization ID
$PowerPlatformEnvironmentUrl = "https://$($PowerPlatformOrg).crm4.dynamics.com" 
    #The URL of the Dataverse environment you want to connect to perform CRUD Operation
$oAuthTokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantId)/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
    <# The “v2 OAuth” endpoint is for the App registration. You’ll want to open the app registration and click the “endpoints” button in the overview area to find it. Then, copy the “OAuth 2.0” token endpoint (v2) URL. #>

# OAuth Body Access Token Request
$authBody = @{
    client_id = $appId;
    client_secret = $secret;    
    # The v2 endpoint for OAuth uses scope instead of resource
    scope = "$($PowerPlatformEnvironmentUrl)/.default"    
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

# Parameters for OAuth Access Token Request
$authParams = @{
    URI = $oAuthTokenEndpoint
    Method = 'POST'
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Body = $authBody
}

# Get Access Token
$authResponseObject = Invoke-RestMethod @authParams -ErrorAction Stop
# Output
$authResponseObject

# My request to get top 5 bots names in this environment
$getDataRequestUri = 'bots?$top=5&$select=name';

$getApiCallParams = @{
    URI = "$($PowerPlatformEnvironmentUrl)/api/data/v9.2/$($getDataRequestUri)"
    Headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "$($authResponseObject.token_type) $($authResponseObject.access_token)"
        "Accept" = "application/json"
        "OData-MaxVersion" = "4.0"
        "OData-Version" = "4.0"
        "If-None-Match" = "null"
    }
    Method = 'GET'
}

# Call API to Get Response
$getApiResponseObject = Invoke-RestMethod @getApiCallParams -ErrorAction Stop
# Output
$getApiResponseObject.value
```

Doing this I'm getting the following error

> **Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"0x80072560","message":"The user is not a member of the organization."}}**

Could someone help to understand Why I'm getting this error?
My service principal as admin don't need to be a member of the organization to get this data as I can do it as admin.

Comment: You are using a local admin account that does not have admin rights on remote machine.  There are different types of admin accounts.  For code to work on remote machine the same admin account has to be on both local and remote machine.  The local and remote machine also need to be in the same group.  Talk to your Group Policy experts.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng but I don't understand your comments. What do you stand for "machines"? I'm talking about Power Platform environment. Normally a Power Platform Admin can access as read only to all dataverse instance in the tenant, he dont need to be a member of the environment.

Comment: You are doing a HTTP Request (Invoke-RestMethod) which is a connection.  The request could be on the same machine (virtual connection) or a remote machine.  Each end of the connection is on a machine (could be same machine).  Power Platform is a Server with a database that clients connect to using HTTP.  Error indicates the client is on a different machine from Power Platform and making a Request.  The request contains credentials and the client credentials (which contains a Group, member of organization) and the Group is not valid on Power Platform.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access webapi for teams environments outside of the teams environment,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-teams-environment#licensing-and-restrictions

also that documentation for the service principal has limitations and does not apply to the webapi of dynamics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powershell-create-service-principal#limitations-of-service-principals